# How to import data from a recently downloaded csv file from your computer automatically in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way in the script editor to automatically pull data from a recently downloaded folder located in your computer and extract the data? From what I have been researching, it seems you can from google drive, however, I am looking for a way to do it from your downloads folder for example.

Comment: About `Is there a way in the script editor to automatically pull data from a recently downloaded folder located in your computer and extract the data?`, if you want to put the data in your local PC to the script of Google Apps Script project, how about using [Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects)? In this case, I think that you can freely select the language you want to use. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Yeah, I found that on my web search. Was hoping it was possible without an API though.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Was hoping it was possible without an API though.`, unfortunately, in the current stage, I think that your goal cannot be achieved without the API. I apologize for this.